# How to select value from CSV containing JSON as a column

Tags: json, csv, jq, miller

I have a weird CSV with one column being JSON data of quite a large size and one is a name. Showing proper JSON formatting for clarity, but the actual file is flat with no newline chars.

```
name, 
{
"field1":
   {"name":"foo",
   "email":"test@gmail.com"},
"field2":{
     "subfield":{
          "subfield2":{
               "active":1,
               "passive":11,
               "running":111
                       }
                  }
           }
}
```

The input without pretty formatting…

```
name,{"field1":{"name":"foo","email":"test@gmail.com"},"field2":{"subfield":{"subfield2":{"active":1,"passive":11,"running":111}}}}
```

I am trying to get the name and all unique values for the subfield 2 into a output (ideally CSV).

```
name, 
active passive running
```

The issue is that the number of fields is not constant and the names of the subfields are not constant either. I have tried using jq, Miller, and sed/awk without much luck since it combines a huge JSON blob and CSV data.

Comment: How "regular" is the part **before** the JSON? Can't you, for instance, split a line at the first(?) comma, then interpret the rest as JSON? Maybe something like `jq -Rr 'scan("([^,]*),(.*)") | .[1] |= (fromjson.field2.subfield.subfield2 | keys_unsorted | join(" ")) | join(", ")'`.

Comment: I don't understand your 2 line sample output when you say *"into a output (ideally CSV)."*. Good luck.

Comment: is this a one line CSV? Do you have only two fields? If no, please add also another sample row and field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run in your sample input

```
<input.txt sed '/name,/d' | jq -cr '.field2.subfield.subfield2 | keys[]' | paste -s -d ' ' | mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header then label name
```

you get

```
name
active passive running
```

The sample output you write, is wrong, because if it's a one field CSV, you do not have the `,` after name, there are no other fields

```
name, 
active passive running
```

But I probably didn't understand what you want

Comment: Note that jq's `keys` will sort the items alphabetically, while `keys_unsorted` retains the original order (for the single sample given they happen to be the same, though).

Comment: @pmf You are right, but I do not know if there is a requirement to retain the original order. If yes, your advice is helpful, thanks

Comment: Interesting answer.  I get an error message that `paste` expects a filename.  Besides that, what's surprised me is the `<filename program` syntax for redirecting input.  I've been using shells for 35 years and I've never noticed that syntax.  Is that specific to Bash or does it work with other shells, too?

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan it's a bash standard input redirection. I do not know if it works in other shell. You should not have any paste error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use your favorite CSV-to-TSV translator to convert the CSV to TSV and then run it through jq like so:

```
jq -rR '
  split("\t") 
  | [[.0], 
     ( .[1]|fromjson|.field2.subfield.subfield2 | keys_unsorted|join(" "))] 
  | @csv'
```

Comment: It's a wrong CSV, it has double quotes and comma inside cells, without the right way to escaping it

Comment: `jq: error (at <stdin>:2): null (null) only strings can be parsed`

Comment: @aborruso - the OP has stated the starting point is CSV and that the illustration shown is not an actual sample.

Comment: @Mr.LanceESloan - how did you provide the TSV to jq?

Comment: @peak the OP has stated that the actual file is flat with no newline chars and that the number of fields is not constant and the names of the subfields are not constant either. The OP did not write that the contents of the cells are also not that. Otherwise each of our solutions was useless.

Comment: @aborruso - Since the OP said the input is CSV, I think you misunderstood the bit about newlines. Specifically, the OP probably meant the newlines in the snippet do not appear in the CSV.

Comment: hi @peak the OP said the input is CSV, but as you can see it's an incorrect CSV. So he/she can't use its favorite CSV-to-TSV translator. The problems is not the newlines but the commas and double quotes.

Comment: @aborruso - the sample shown is obviously not CSV, and the OP explained that it was not supposed to be.  Anyway, both the question and the sample made sense to me,  so I went with that, even if the [mcve] guidelines were not followed to the letter.

Comment: @peak I'm glad we're saying the same thing:  it's not a CSV

Answer (score -2):

I spent some time with sed and it got me what I needed using the below:

```
sed -e 's/.*subfield2\(.*\)}}}.*/\1/' input.txt
```

Comment: Since you're the OP, I guess if you're satisfied with that, then I guess that's good enough.  However, the output of that command doesn't look like the output you said you wanted to see.